# array is composite data type but how?

Tags: java, arrays

> Array is composite data type.
> A composite data type is one whose values are composed of component values
> (possibly values chosen from other data types.) Example of composite data
> type is array.
>
> ```
> int a[ ] = {1,2,3,4,5};
> ```

In above example, as far as I understand it, is composite because an array-of-int value is comprised of some number of element values chosen from the int type. Using composite data types, we can manage multiple pieces of related data as a single datum. An array is the concept of using a number of values declared with in the same data type.

Please explain in simple way array is composite data type. Explain this statement with example?

Comment: You've just explained it yourself. What are you unsure about exactly?

Comment: A composite data type is one which is composed with various primitive data type. A class defined with various primitive data types such as int, double etc;but i am using only one data type for array initialization that is int

Comment: The element types are irrelevant, important is only that there are several elements.

Comment: just rewording - an array is a composition of same type of values i.e. `int[] iArray = new int[5] ;` is same as a composition of type `aIntCompose { int i1, i2,i3,i4,i5 }`

Comment: When someone talks about "composite" I think about things like [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) or [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). I've never thought about calling an array a composite but actually, per definition of the word, it is one. The explanation you've provided seems absolutely logical to me. But you should see arrays then as a composition of elements and not a composition of types; then the confusion is probably gone.

Comment: you are taking instantiation as example for composition. may i take example of initialization of an array a [] = {1,2,3,4}?@PrasadU

Answer (score 0):

> A class defined with various primitive data types such as int, double etc;but i am using only one data type for array initialization that is int

Consider the following example:

```
class Test {
    int a, b, c;
    Test() {
        a = 1 ; b = 2 ; c = 3;
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test object = new Test();
    }
}
```

As per your definition, in this case, even the class `Test` will be a primitive data type because it only `int` type values. However, this is not true.

As @Henry stated,

> The element types are irrelevant, important is only that there are several elements

So basically, I would say a more precise definition for composite data type would be:

> The data types which are created by the user, which *may* consist of *one or more* primitive data types, created **under a single declaration** are called Composite data types.

Going by that definition, arrays are also composite data types.